# SignalR client app on Mac

Tags: .net, node.js, macos, signalr

I'm trying to create a console app in Mac OS which connects to SignalR hub server (.net on Windows). This console should also perform some file system operations and run another app - that's why it is not a browser app.

I tried to look at Node.js but didn't find a good SignalR client lib. [Signalr-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/signalr-client) supports only WebSockets. I need at least 2 transports - WebSockets and one not WebSockets.

Next, I looked at .Net Core but also didn't find a simple solution for this like [Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/) package for regular .Net.

Can someone recommend a good and a simple solution for such kind of task? I'd like to find a simple and light approach.